# casting char buffer to a c structure

Tags: c, casting, struct

In the code below i was expecting another output! :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _cust {
        char    customerId[10];
        char    customerPhone[10];
        char    customerDep[4];
} cust;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        cust    *newCust;
        const char testChar[] = "11W35A5CT-012345678-CORP";

        newCust = (cust *)malloc(sizeof(struct _cust));
        newCust = (cust *)testChar;

        printf("CustomerId = %s\n", newCust->customerId);
        printf("CustomerPhone = %s\n", newCust->customerPhone);
        printf("CustomerDep = %s\n", newCust->customerDep);

        return 0;
}
```

And the output is :

```
CustomerId = 11W35A5CT-012345678-CORP
CustomerPhone = 012345678-CORP
CustomerDep = CORP
```

I was expecting this output :

```
CustomerId = 11W35A5CT-
CustomerPhone = 012345678-
CustomerDep = CORP
```

Can someone explain to me why this? Thanks.

EDIT :

To avoid confusing on my post i'm adding here the gdb trace when debugging this program:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048474: file name.c, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/evariste/src/customer_files/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff2c4) at name.c:11
11  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
(gdb) n
13      const char testChar[] = "11W35A5CT-012345678-CORP";
(gdb) n
15      newCust = (cust *)malloc(sizeof(struct _cust));
(gdb) n
16      newCust = (cust *)testChar;
(gdb) n
21      printf("CustomerId = %s\n", newCust->customerId);
(gdb) print *newCust
$1 = {customerId = "11W35A5CT-", customerPhone = "012345678-", 
  customerDep = "CORP"}
```

So whey here i see that customerId = "11W35A5CT-" and when i try printf i got the whole string?

Comment: You have a memory leak in that.  You need to use memcpy, not just overwrite the pointer.  Also, potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: It doesn't apply in this case because you're only using `char`s, but you should be aware of [structure padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) when interpreting raw data with structs.

Comment: @corbin : Yes i know ther's a memory leak but it's not the explanation, when i do free before return it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughin : when i use __attribute__((__packed__)) i got the same result, so it's not a padding problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf()` will output until it hits a `\0` which signals the end of the string.  There's no `\0` after any of the hyphens and so `printf()` will print from the start position you gave it to the end of what's in `testChar`.

Also, you leaked away the memory the call to `malloc` allocated for you.  Perhaps you want to *copy* the string into the struct?

Comment: @QuantumMrchanic : it's ok for the memory leak, i'm aware of that, if your answer was ok, whey i don't have the same output three times?

Comment: Read Corbin's answer which will explain why you don't see the same thing three times.  Short version -- because you're handing `printf` a different start position each time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an over simplification, but hopefully it will illustrate what's happening.

```
typedef struct _cust {
        char    customerId[10];
        char    customerPhone[10];
        char    customerDep[4];
} cust;
```

What the compiler will do with this is pretend it's a 24 character blob. Assume that blob is rooted at a char* called x.  Then customerId is just an alias for x+0, customerPhone is an alias for x + 10, and customerDep an alias for x + 20.

So, what happening when you over write the pointer with the string is that x = testChar.

That means customerId is &testChar[0], customerPhone is &testChar[10] and so on.

The problem with this is that printf and friends, as QuantumMechanic said, do not have a concept of a range for a string.  A C string is just beginning until null byte.  That means that printf() on customId will go from testChar[0] until it hits a null byte which will be the end of the testchar string.

To do what you want, each string will have to have a null byte inserted at the end of it, meaning your overlay like this not going to work (also I believe your overlay could result in undefined behavior, but I'm not sure).

(Or you could do like mteckert suggested.)

Comment: thanks i understand what the compiler do, i edit my post and i add the gdb output, please refer to it.

Comment: That's happening because GDB knows it's a char[10].  printf does not.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced :), How can i extract the value of this fileds?

Comment: @iPadDevloperJr I don't know why you're not convinced.  That's just how C works.  A pointer in C carries no information other than the address and the type.  And what do you mean how can you extract?  Have you read mteckert's answer?

Comment: I want to be able to do the mapping correctly like this customerId = 11W35A5CT-, customerPhone = 012345678-, etc...

Comment: Then you will need to put null bytes at the end of each copied string (you won't be able to just lay the string over).

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `malloc`, specify the size of the string to print in the `printf` format specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _cust {
    char    customerId[10];
    char    customerPhone[10];
    char    customerDep[4];
} cust;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cust    *newCust;
    const char testChar[] = "11W35A5CT-012345678-CORP";

    newCust = (cust *)testChar;

    printf("CustomerId = %.*s\n", 
        sizeof(newCust->customerId), newCust->customerId);
    printf("CustomerPhone = %.*s\n", 
        sizeof(newCust->customerPhone), newCust->customerPhone);
    printf("CustomerDep = %.*s\n", 
        sizeof(newCust->customerDep),newCust->customerDep);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i don't understand why this happen, normally when you cast a struct to a region of memory all the components of the struct are assigned to this region by moving the offset of each element size until reach the end.

Comment: `printf` doesn't care about struct components. As QuantumMechanic said, it prints until it encounters the null character.